# Is There a way to share data from one component to another component which are in different modules by using @Input decorator

Tags: angular, typescript

I have two different components in separate modules i am importing one module into another module and referring imported modules component html selector in the module's component, sample text is printing in `<router-outlet>` when i tried sending data using @Input decorator to the other component it is throwing an error saying 
 `Error: Template parse errors:
 Can't bind to 'themeingColors' since it isn't a known property of 'app-color- 
 palette-container'.` I got to know by the error that components should be under same module to get benefit by `@Input`

But my question is there a way we can achieve passing data by using `@Input` decorator even if the components are in different modules?

Comment: Yes, you can pass inputs to other components, whether or not they are in the same module. How could you possibly use libraries of components such as ng-bootstrap or angular material If you could not do that? If you want help with your code, then post it.

Comment: It looks a lot like a typo on the word "themeingColors". But hard to see without some more code.

Comment: Yes, you can pass the data by using @Input decorator even if the components are in different modules

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of sharing data between components: Input/Output decors, shared service and passing the components as reference. If they are in separate modules(and if they are lazy loaded), you should use the shared service aproach. Where you instantiate a service on app initialization and use it as a global ''state'' container for such things as themes. But dont overuse it for everything cuz it get really messy.